# CKEditor allow onclick attribute in links

Tags: typo3, ckeditor4.x, typo3-8.x

I'm using CKEditor in TYPO3 8.7 with a separate YAML-File for configuration.

This works fine, except when I want to add an `onclick`-event to a link-tag. 
CKEditor always strips the onclick-attribute from the link.

I can't find a description online, how to allow the onclick-attribute.
Anyone having an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

In the YAML-File under editor -> config add the following:

```
extraAllowedContent: "*(*)[*]"
```

This allows all attributes to all tags. This is basically what I needed, since I'm using CKEditor only in the backend, so there's no security-risk.

If you want to allow only onclick use:

```
extraAllowedContent: "*(*)[onclick]"
```

Allows onclick on every tag.

I didn't go any deeper into this as it only drives me crazy... ;)